# element.innerHTML = -> This document requires 'TrustedHTML'

Tags: javascript

`element.innerHTML = ...` is throwing the following error:
`This document requires 'TrustedHTML'`.

I found this documentation about it that I have trouble understanding: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/require-trusted-types-for

How should one go about doing a `element.innerHTML = ...` with `trustedHTML`? Do they mean that the snippet below just has to be placed somewhere before `element.innerHTML = ...`?

```
const sanitizer = trustedTypes.createPolicy('foo', {
    createHTML: (input) => DOMPurify.sanitize(input)
});
```

Apologies for being basic here, I just want to understand what I'm getting into.

Comment: yes, and then you use it like this: `element.innerHTML = sanitizer.createHTML(yourHTML)`

Comment: just tried on chrome, I get this error `Uncaught ReferenceError: DOMPurify is not defined` I hope you're luckier

Comment: Thanks - I'm lucky that it works for me, but I don't if my users are as lucky as I am :)

Answer (score 0):

1- [`DOMPurify`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dompurify) is a library and not an internal part of `javascript` or `html`. So you need to add it to your project to be able to use it.

I guess the framework you're using for your project, has it as an dependency.

2- The error is caused by `Content-Security-Policy:require-trusted-types-for` which is still an experimental technology and chances are not all browsers (firefox for example) fully support it yet.

So to use this feature in your code

1- add a trusted type to your code: (`foo` can be replaced by any name you want)

```
// Content-Security-Policy: require-trusted-types-for 'script'; trusted-types foo;
```

2- create a policy for your `trusted-type` that returns safe and sanitized html:

```
const sanitizer = trustedTypes.createPolicy("foo", {
    createHTML: (input) => DOMPurify.sanitize(input),
  });
```

3- Then use it to filter dangerous html content

```
elm.innerHTML = sanitizer.createHTML(attackerInput);
```

You are not forced to use `DOMPurify` (though you'd better to). You can do the sanitizing yourself.

```
const sanitizer = trustedTypes.createPolicy("foo", {
   createHTML: (input) => {
     const cleanContent = // Your custom sanitizing logic goes here
     return cleanContent;
   }
});
```

Comment: That regex example is unsuitable for most security purposes. I suggest removing it or replacing it with a thorough escaping example.

Comment: @Ry- That was simply to show how DOMPurify can be replaced with a custom code. But as it may be misleading for some I edited the answer.